# helm chart - value file variables

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am using a helm chart (with sub-charts) to deploy my application.
I am using a value file for setting values.

I am looking a way to set variables in my value file (or any other place) that will be valid for my value file.

I have some sections (services) in my value files that I need to use the same value in it
so I am looking for a variable in my value file.
Is there any way that I can use variables for my value file?
Thx

Comment: I'm not aware that helm has built-in support for that. You could do a preprocessing, e.g. using [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/).
Say, define a `values.mustache` file with variables inside, then pass it through mustache with a data (variable values) file to generate the `values.yaml` file.

Answer (score 1):

Helm on its own can't do this.

If you control all of the charts and subcharts, you can allow specific values to have embedded Go templating.  Helm includes a [`tpl`](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#using-the-tpl-function) extension function that will let you render an arbitrary string as a template.  So if you have values

```yaml
global:
  commonKey: some value
otherKey: '{{ .Values.global.commonKey }}'
```

then you can render

```yaml
- name: OTHER_KEY
  value: '{{ tpl .Values.otherKey . }}'
```

But, you have to use `tpl` every place you access the key value(s); if you don't control the subcharts you may not be able to do this.

Higher-level tools may also let you do this.  I'm familiar in particular with [Helmfile](https://github.com/roboll/helmfile) which lets you declare multiple Helm charts and their settings, but also lets you use almost-Helm templating in many places.  So your `helmfile.yaml` could specify:

```yaml
environments:
  default:
    # These values are available when rendering templates in this file
    values:
      - commonKey: some value
releases:
  - name: my-service
    namespace: my-service
    chart: ./charts/my-service
    values:
      # List items can be file names or YAML dictionaries.
      # If it's a dictionary, arbitrary nested values.yaml content.
      # If it's a *.yaml.gotmpl file name, templating is applied to the file.
      - otherKey: '{{ .Values.commonKey }}'
        yetAnotherKey: '{{ .Values.commonKey }}'
      - ./my-service.yaml.gotmpl
```

[Helmsman](https://github.com/Praqma/helmsman) is simpler, but can only set chart values from environment variables; but I believe you can reference the same environment variable in different `setString:` options.  You could also do something similar with the [Terraform Helm provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs), using Terraform's native expression syntax, particularly if you're already familiar with Terraform.